# php subdomain.domain presumed as extension on str_replace

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

I am trying to strip filename.extension from my local domain

local domain virtual host: `http://cms.local/`

and on str_replace I am trying to remove `index.php` to keep it dynamic my main concern is to consider the fact that `filename.extension` could be anything.

my code to do so:

`private static function removeFilename($url) {
    $file_info = pathinfo($url);
    return isset($file_info['extension']) ? str_replace($file_info['filename'] . "." . $file_info['extension'], "", $url) : $url;
  }`

where `$url` is unparsed url based on [this post](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#106731).

Considering that my url is `http://cms.local/index.php` everything is going smoothly but in case my url is just `http://cms.local/`; without filename.extension, `str_replace` function removes `cms.local` as if it is the filename.extension, leaving just `http:///`.

Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static function removeFilename($url) {
    return substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);
}
```

[`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) Returns the portion of string specified by the start and length parameters.

[`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) Find the numeric position of the last occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

This will not work if url is http://cms.local without the last slash.

**EDIT**

If you need to keep query string and remove just filename + extension:

```
function removeFilename($url) {
    $queryString = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    return substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') + 1) . "?" . $queryString;
}
```

> [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
>   function parses a URL and returns an associative array containing any
>   of the various components of the URL that are present. The values of
>   the array elements are not URL decoded.
>
> ### component
>
> Specify one of PHP_URL_SCHEME, PHP_URL_HOST, PHP_URL_PORT,
>   PHP_URL_USER, PHP_URL_PASS, PHP_URL_PATH, **PHP_URL_QUERY** or
>   PHP_URL_FRAGMENT to retrieve just a specific URL component as a string
>   (except when PHP_URL_PORT is given, in which case the return value
>   will be an integer).

**EDIT 2**
Final solution with adding a trailing slash if url is http://cms.local

```
private static function addTrailingSlash($url) {
    $url = parse_url($url);
    if(!isset($url['path'])) $url['path'] = '/';
    $surl = $url['scheme']."://".$url['host'].$url['path'].'?'.$url['query'];
    return $surl;   
}

private static function removeFilename($url) {
    $url = addTrailingSlash($url);
    $queryString = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
    return substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, '/') + 1) . "?" . $queryString;
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks. Conveniently this url will always be redirected to cms.local/?page=?, thank you for the quick answer, m8 ) Sorry, I cannot up-vote your answer my reputation on stack is too low, though.

Comment: I edited my answer if you needed to keep the query string on your url. This will return `cms.local/?page=6` from `cms.local/index.php?page=6`

Comment: I added a final solution with a function to add a trailing slash if not present. I didn't try it yet but let me know!